# Intuition behind Gambler's Ruin Problem Solution

Tags: probability, markov-chains

In case of gambler's ruin (fair) the probability that a process starting at state $j$ eventually will reach state $N$ before state 0 is $\frac{j}{N}$. I understand that it should be proportional to $j$. But, intuitively, why $\frac{j}{N}$ ?. I am asking intuitive answer. Formal proof is available in any standard text book.

Comment: Once you understand that the probability is $\sim j$ (and in fact that is the less trivial part), then it is clear that the proportional factor is such that the probability is $0$ if $j=0$ and $1$ if $j=N$. The proportionality itself folows from tha fact that $f(j)$ should be the average of $f(j-1)$ and $f(j+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of your position is always $j$.  So that means the probability of getting to $N$ times the "weight" of going to $N$ has to equal the probability of getting to 0 times the "weight" of going to 0.  In symbols:

$$P(N) * (N-j) = P(0) * j$$

And since $P(0) + P(N) = 1$, we get that $P(N) = j/N$.

Answer (score 1):

here's an intuitive way to arrive at P(j)= j/N.

the game is fair,  so the  avg gain per game should be zero.
Avg gain = ( (Prob to win) x gain per won game)  - ((Prob to lose) x loss per lost game)    = (Prob to win) x (N-j) -  (Prob to lose) x (j)   = 0

But (Prob to win  + Prob to lose) = 1,
so (Prob to lose) = (1 - (prob to win) ).

so  (Prob to Win)  x (N-j) - (1 - Prob to Win) x j = 0
      (Prob to Win) x N  =  j

### (Prob to Win) = j/N

Comment: how does this solution use the fact that p = q = 0.5?