# Simple martingale question: expected stopping time for drunken walk

Tags: probability, martingales, stopping-times

I have a question about the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questons/1926660/random-walk-with-martingale-solution):

> A symmetric random walk, i.e. with equal probability one makes a unit step left and right, respectively. Given positive integers x,yx,y we position walker at place x.x. What is the probability to reach x+yx+y before we reach 0?

The answer used a martingale argument, but I didn't understand the following line:

> Let $p$ be the probability of reaching $x+y$ (rather than reaching 0). So the probability of reaching $0$ is $1−p$ (note that the probability of never reaching either end is $0$). Let $Z$ be the position at the end of the walk.
>
> We have $\mathbb E[Z]=p⋅(x+y)+ (1−p)⋅0.$

Why is this true?

Comment: Finally, I discovered that question was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549216/intuition-behind-gamblers-ruin-problem-solution